# Migration tool for twitter bootstrap 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-2

My app is based on rails 4, and it seems I have to migrate it from twitter bootstrap 2 to twitter bootstrap 3

But, it seems that its not easy task, as I am using lots of haml and erb files.

Is there any gem there that would replace the classes names?
Whats the recommended approach to migrate?

Comment: Follow the official migration guide: http://getbootstrap.com/migration/

Comment: That's a pain.. no time either..

Comment: C'est la vie. There is http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com but it's incomplete and only supports HTML.